# how to get data from android app by bot

Tags: android, web-crawler

Is it possible get data from android app?

for example,
some app have the news list or products list

Is it possible to get the news/products data?

We all know it's easy to get data in web by some spider/crawler tools.

How to do it from APP?

Comment: you have two applications and you want to get from one to the other data?

Answer (score 0):

> We all know it's easy to get data in web by some spider/crawler tools.

From this I assume you're trying to do what Google has been doing with the web - create a automated program to gather data from available app.

If that's the case: I'm afraid it's not possible. As far as I know you can't fetch data from apps unless they're allowing third-party access.